# MySQL 5.7, sort table by column name using a variable in Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple table with some data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MY_TABLE`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MY_TABLE` (
  `id` CHAR(40) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_bin' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE` (`id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE` (`id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE` (`id`) VALUES (3);
```

Now I have a procedure to retrieve this data ordering from a column.
This works as expected:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure()
BEGIN

  SELECT id AS columnAlias FROM `MY_TABLE`
  ORDER BY columnAlias;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure();  /* Returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 */
```

As well as this:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure()
BEGIN

  SELECT id AS columnAlias FROM `MY_TABLE`
  ORDER BY -columnAlias;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure(); /* Should return 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 */
```

Now, my case: the column name has to be passed from the procedure, so I do:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(IN data JSON)

BEGIN

  SET @sortBy  = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.sortBy'));
  
  SELECT id AS columnAlias FROM `MY_TABLE`
  ORDER BY @sortBy;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure('{"sortBy": "columnAlias"}');  /* Should return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 */
CALL test_procedure('{"sortBy": "-columnAlias"}'); /* Should return 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 */
```

But can't make it work. Any help will be welcome.

---

EDIT:

Given the solution by @bill_karwin I tried to use a CASE, testing agains my variable:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure(IN data JSON)

BEGIN

  SET @sortBy  = JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DATA, '$.sortBy'));
  
  SELECT id AS columnAlias FROM `MY_TABLE`
  ORDER BY 
    CASE @sortBy 
      WHEN "columnAlias" THEN columnAlias
      WHEN "-columnAlias" THEN -columnAlias
    END
 ;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure('{"sortBy": "-columnAlias"}');
```

Doesnt work though, returns `1, 2, 3`, while it should be reversed as I'm passing the string with a minus prepended: `-columnAlias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CASE expression:

```
SELECT id AS columnAlias FROM `MY_TABLE`
ORDER BY CASE @sortBy WHEN 'updated_at' THEN updated_at 
                      WHEN 'user_id' THEN user_id
                      ELSE id END;
```

Some people use dynamic SQL, but the CASE expression solution is good because it automatically checks the input against a fixed set of columns, so you don't accidentally cause an SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Interesting! How would it look the Dynamic SQL?

Comment: In SP i'd recommend 2 separate, independent queries (and only one of them is executed, depends on parameter value) rather than CASE in ORDER BY.

Comment: An example would be really helpful!